# jsdoc @returns - return function with optional parameter

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I have a hook which returns:

```
/**
 *
 * @returns {[
 *   AuthState,
 *   (providerName: string, redirectSignIn: boolean) => Promise<boolean>,
 *   () => Promise<void>
 * ]}
 */
```

How to describe **redirectSignIn** parameter to be optional?

Answer (score 0):

try adding a default value 'undefined'

```
/**
 *
 * @returns {[
 *   AuthState,
 *   (providerName: string, redirectSignIn: boolean=undefined) => Promise<boolean>,
 *   () => Promise<void>
 * ]}
 */
```

worked in my case:

```
@returns {(function(api:object, action:string, args:array, opts:object=undefined, cb:function=undefined): Promise|void)}
```